# Problema objetos de memoria sobreescritos al consultar base de datos

Tags: java, hibernate

Buenos días,

Tengo un problema que me lleva fastidiando ya dos días. El problema en cuestión, es que tengo un objecto X con unos datos en memoria, y al consultar en bbdd dicho objeto X para comprobar si lo que tengo en memoria y bbdd es lo mismo, se cambia mi objeto de memoria con lo que hay en bbdd.

```
    //Operaciones operacionMemoria --> Este objeto contiene los datos en memoria, diferentes de los de BBDD.

    OperacionesDaoImpl dao = new OperacionesDaoImpl(EntityManager);
    OperacionesId idOperacion = new OperacionesId(idOperacion, beo); 
    Operaciones operacionbbdd = null;
    try { 
        operacionbbdd = dao.getOperacionById(idOperacion);
```

Es justo tras consultar la operación en BBDD, que también se cambia la operacionMemoria que tenía los cambios.

¿Alguna idea?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Añade el código para que podamos ver lo que ocurre.

Comment: Añádelo a la pregunta no como comentario. Para eso, justo debajo de las etiquetas tienes el botón editar

Comment: También deberías leer el [ask]

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Antoñoli!, es importante realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Además es **muy importante revisar [ask]** que te da brinda información para realizar una buena pregunta, esta sea bien recibida en la comunidad y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas!.

Answer (score -1):

Seguramente tu aplicación lea dicho objeto y Hibernate lo mantenga enlazado al modelo, con lo que cuando lo vuelvas a pedir reutilice la instancia existente, actualizando los campos.

Una solución es, cuando obtengas la versión que quieres mantener aparte de la base de datos, hagas una copia manual del mismo.

La otra solución es usar [`Session.evict()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#evict%28java.lang.Object%29) para que Hibernate se "olvide" de esa instancia.

Comment: Lo probaré, muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿El voto negativo es porque no ha funcionado o hay otro motivo?